# Array of bytes from View in android

Tags: android

I have a drawing view, and i am trying to get array of bytes from that view on button click

this is my code:

```
public void onClick(    
drawView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        getContentResolver(), drawView.getDrawingCache(),
                        UUID.randomUUID().toString() + ".png", "drawing");
        }
}
```

please help!

Comment: in my android application

Comment: you'll probably have to clarify your question along with adding a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If view is ImageView first convert into bitmap then convert into byte array

**Convert ImageView to Bitmap**

```
public static Bitmap getImageViewAsBitmap(ImageView imageView) {
        imageView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
        return bmap;
    }
```

**Convert Bitmap to Byte Array**

```
public byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);
        return outputStream.toByteArray();
    }
```

**Convert Byte Array to Bitmap**

```
public static Bitmap getByteArrayAsBitmap(byte[] bitmap) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bitmap));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return bm;
    }
```

To call these methods like that:

provide **imageview** give **bitmap**

```
Bitmap m1Bitmap= getImageViewAsBitmap(myimageView);
```

provide **bitmap** give **byte array**

```
byte[] mbyteArray =getBitmapAsByteArray(mBitmap);
```

provide **byte array** give **bitmap**

```
Bitmap m2Bitmap= getByteArrayAsBitmap(byte[] bitmap);
```